# File sharing, restricting access rights in a workgroup on a network. How does one login?

Tags: windows, powershell, file-sharing, shared-directory

If I've created a user account and gave read/write access to this user for some shared folder, how to actually use the credentials of that user from another computer, meaning, how to access the shared folder from another computer on a local network using the aforementioned user account?

And is there a way to do this programmatically? Preferably, with powershell.

Comment: Did you try PSRemoting? From the remote workstation establish a session. Verify that you can see the folder. Try to enter the protected file. If you receive an authorization error message enter the credentials into your remoting session. 
But most of all, provide some code so we can help you with a particular problem you encounter. ;)

Comment: @Alex_P, the part about doing it programmatically is optional. From a brief look, it seems PSRemoting needs both ends to participate; it would be much better if the one with the shared folder didn't have to run any commands. And it also shouldn't be interactive at all. Though, again, I'm equally concerned of how to do this as an average user (with just GUI).
To be more clear on the problem: for me this sharing stuff is a dark matter for now.

Comment: The shared folder I assume has a UNC path that looks like `\\<servername>\Foldername`. With GUI, u can use the Run window to access it directly by providing the UNC path. Or you can Map it to local machine as a network drive. To do this programatically, create a `PSCredential` object and use that with `New-PSDrive -Name "Share" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\<servername>\<foldername>" -Credential $pscredential`. You can access the mapped location from this path `Share:\\``